# What happens to the energy returned by capacitive loads in AC?

Tags: ac, generator

Power alternates equally between cycles of positive and negative. (Figure above) This means that power is being alternately absorbed from and returned to the source. If the source were a mechanical generator, it would take (practically) no net mechanical energy to turn the shaft, because no power would be used by the load. The generator shaft would be easy to spin, and the inductor would not become warm as a resistor would.
how is the net mechanical energy zero. Is the power fed back to generator to turn it? If so, can you show how the connections are made in generator for this to work?

Comment: Figure above?  I am not seeing it.  Please clarify what type of devices.  Resistor, capacitor or inductor.

Comment: (The mechanical effect is called *moment ripple*.)

Comment: What is the *inductor* mentioned where the title is about `capacitive loads`?

Answer (score 1):

> The generator shaft would be easy to spin

Not really.  That's like stating that a cart with round wheels is as easy to pull on an even road as a cart with square wheels because the net energy is zero.  The generator will alternately deliver energy to the capacitor and take it back, with rotational inertia taking it over the bumps.  The net energy may be zero, but it will be a ratchety spin that requires good bearings depending on the ratio of energy stored in the capacitor and in the generator's rotational inertia.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the source that donated energy in the first place. If it's a spinning generator, then the energy sourced by the generator is delivered in the form of torque × angular velocity. When the energy is returned, the result is a torque in the opposite direction, but with direction of rotation unchanged.

In other words, the energy donated to whatever's connected to the shaft would act to slow rotation, but the returned energy would act to accelerate it again.

What happens when you compress a spring? The energy of muscular exertion, the force × distance energy you donated to compress it, will be returned as an almost equal force × distance work to restore the prior equilibrium. How that returned energy is dissipated in your muscles depends on physiology.